# Conditional template based on data in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am using underscore.js html template to render html for the following json (simplified):

```
[
 {
   "$id": "1",
   "Type": 3000,
   "Date": "2014-02-26T07:17:03+05:00"
 },
 {
   "$id": "1",
   "Type": 2000,
   "Date": "2014-02-26T07:17:03+05:00"
 },

]
```

I have to render Html for each item in the array based on the `Type` field. The html for each `Type` is quite different and my current template is littered with html and if else conditions , pretty much like this:

```
<script type="text/template" class="template">
   <% _.each(streams, function(data) { if(data.Type == 3000){ %>
   // Some long html here for type 3000

   <% if(data.Type == 2000){%>
   // html for type 2000
   <% }}}); %>
</script>
```

How can I avoid writing if else conditions in the template and possibly create a template for each `type' so I can easily maintain my templates.

Comment: Narrow down (or copy) the collection before parsing it into the template using underscore functions (since you're using it already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by calling templates inside the template like:

```
<script type="text/template" class="template">
    <div>
      <% _.each(data, function(child) { %>
          <%= _.template($('.template_'+child.Type).html())(child) %>
      <% }); %>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" class="template_3000">
    <div>
      3000 Template
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" class="template_2000">
    <div>
      2000 Template
    </div>
</script>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/L2b9H/ for working example.